# adding header from column text file to another file

Tags: linux

I have a tab delimited column text like below

text1

```
A  CD274    PDCD1LG2  CD276   PDCD1LG2  CD274 .......
B  NEK2     NEK6      NEK10   NEK10     NEKL-4 ......
C  TNFAIP3  OTUD7B    OTUD7B  TNFAIP3   TNFAIP3......
D  DUSP16   DUSP4     DUSP8   VHP-1     DUSP8........
E  AGO2     AGO2      AGO2    AGO2      AGO2.........
```

Text2

```
header1
header2
header3
header4
.
.
.
```

how can i give header  as shown below

```
   header1    header2  header3   header4  header5
A  CD274    PDCD1LG2  CD276   PDCD1LG2  CD274
B  NEK2     NEK6      NEK10   NEK10     NEKL-4
C  TNFAIP3  OTUD7B    OTUD7B  TNFAIP3   TNFAIP3
D  DUSP16   DUSP4     DUSP8   VHP-1     DUSP8
E  AGO2     AGO2      AGO2    AGO2      AGO2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) way :

```
awk '
    {
        if (NR!=FNR) {
            if (FNR==1) {
                printf "\t"
                for (i in arr){printf "%s\t", arr[i]}
                print ""
            }
            print
        }
        else{
            arr[c++]=$1
        }
    }
' file2 file1
```

Comment: I just want the first line in Tex2 to be the header in the second column in text1 and the second line in Tex2 to be the header third column in text1.....etc. but this code put the header in random order

Answer (score 0):

**`printf`** + **`paste`** solution:

```
printf "\t%s\n" "$(paste -sd'\t' file2)" && cat file1
```

Sample output:

```
    header1 header2 header3 header4 header5
A   CD274   PDCD1LG2    CD276   PDCD1LG2    CD274   
B   NEK2    NEK6    NEK10   NEK10   NEKL-4  
C   TNFAIP3 OTUD7B  OTUD7B  TNFAIP3 TNFAIP3
D   DUSP16  DUSP4   DUSP8   VHP-1   DUSP8
E   AGO2    AGO2    AGO2    AGO2    AGO2
```

Comment: This works fine, but  i wanted to write the result to another file so that i did like this `(printf "\t%s\n" "$(paste -sd'\t' file2)" && cat file1) > file3`